# TeX Live (and MiKTeX) + Windows 7 + Texmaker problem with expl3.sty

Tags: expl3

I recently updated MiKTeX and I can't compile anymore xelatex through Texmaker simple multilingual tex e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document} 
Hello world Χαίρε κόσμε 
\end{document}
```

obtaining errors concerning expl3.sty

I read a lot of solutions in various places and to be frank I got rather confused. I removed MiKTeX and installed TeX Live instead but the problem persists.

The error part of my logfile is:

```
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty
Package: l3bootstrap 2011/09/10 v2798 L3 Experimental bootstrap code)
Package: l3names 2011/09/07 v2776 L3 Experimental namespace for primitives)

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \filename 

l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...e \@cls@pkg \space provides `\filename 
                                              '\@gobble \on@line .^^J
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `expl3',
           but the package provides `'.
```

followed by 6 more "! Undefined control sequence." full messages concluding with:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `l3intexpr.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.83 \RequirePackage
                { 
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

Texmaker classifies the error messages in the expl3.sty package.

---

Thank you for your help. Unfortunately the problem is still there...

MikTex shows that "no updates available" There is just an expl3.sty file inside the l3kernel folder. I can't find it directly from TexLive Manager (just as a filename inside the l3kernel package)

The complete log file is:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (Web2C 2011) (format=xelatex 2011.9.21)  
22 SEP 2011 11:30
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, an
cientgreek, ibycus, ukenglish, usenglishmax, monogreek, greek, loaded.
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
Package: xltxtra 2010/09/20 v0.5e Improvements for the "XeLaTeX" format

(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2011/09/18 v2.2a Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX

 (./expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty
Package: l3bootstrap 2011/09/10 v2798 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
)
Package: l3names 2011/09/07 v2776 L3 Experimental namespace for primitives
)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \filename 

l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...e \@cls@pkg \space provides `\filename 
                                              '\@gobble \on@line .^^J
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `expl3',
           but the package provides `'.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \filedate 
                  v\fileversion  \filedescription 
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \filedate  v\fileversion 
                                 \filedescription 
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...te  v\fileversion  \filedescription 

l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<write> Package: \@gtempa \space \filedate 
                                        v\fileversion  \filedescription 
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...gtempa \space \filedate  v\fileversion 
                                               \filedescription 
l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...edate  v\fileversion  \filedescription 

l.55 ...\filedate}{\fileversion}{\filedescription}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Package:   v 
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count88
)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty
Package: l3basics 2011/09/12 v2817 L3 Experimental basic definitions
)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty
Package: l3expan 2011/09/12 v2812 L3 Experimental argument expansion
)
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty
Package: l3tl 2011/09/12 v2812 L3 Experimental token lists
)

! LaTeX Error: File `l3intexpr.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.83 \RequirePackage
                { 
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1610 strings out of 495646
 24751 string characters out of 3186730
 60250 words of memory out of 3000000
 4819 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 36 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 37i,0n,27p,339b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 No pages of output.
```

Comment: The files have been rearranged: expl3 is now in l3kernel, l3packages and l3experimental. This means that TeXsystem like TeXlive must remove older packages (expl3 and xpackages). This didn't always work. Probably you still have older versions around which are found first. Remove them with the texlive manager manually.

Comment: The names look okay to me, but I wonder what is earlier in the log. @user8019, Can we see the _complete_ log file?

Comment: @user8019 I have edited your log data into the question.

Answer (score 5):

The answer lies in the log line

```
 (./expl3.sty
```

This indicates that `expl3` is being loaded from the *current* folder, not the TeX Live folder (and thus explains why the problem was common to MiKTeX and TeX Live). Delete the file `expl3` from the folder containing your `.tex` file, and the issue should go away. You may also need to remove any other 'oddly-placed' `.sty` files.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. I feel really embarassed. I was so confused with various answers to similar problems; I tried so many tricks, that in the end I "shot my own foot".

Comment: Oh, @user8019, I did not say earlier: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) In general, it's a good idea to change your user ID to something a bit more memorable than `userXXXX` :-)

Answer (score 1):

What solved the issue for me was running a MiKTeX/Maintenance/Update ***as user***   (not as Admin). I found out there was an obsolete l3kernel to be removed (even though that package had already been removed in the Admin interface).

Explanation is here: http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2111/

Comment: This solved the problem I had with expl3. Thanks.